# Vibed: error: 411 Length Required

Tags: http, d, http-status-codes, vibed

I am trying to get server response code with next code:

```
import std.stdio;
import vibe.core.log;
import vibe.http.client;
import vibe.stream.operations;
import vibe.http.status;

void main()
{
        requestHTTP("http://www.example.org/", (scope req) {
            req.method = HTTPMethod.POST;
        },
        (scope res) {
            logInfo("Response: %s", res.statusCode);
        }
    );
}
```

But I am getting response code 411, that mean "Length Required". What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The problem was solved using:
`req.method = HTTPMethod.GET;` instead of `POST` method.

Comment: Most likely it is because server expects `POST` requests to have actual body and/or `Content-Length` header and you don't provide any in above example.